# Selenium Click on non button element

Tags: java, facebook, selenium

I Want to click on a Facebook Post Like button using Selenium and Java With no Luck .

Here is the code:

```
driver.navigate().to("https://www.facebook.com/DavidGuetta/posts/10153196593446356");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Like')]")).click();
```

But sadly it does not work .. 
i've tried this too

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[contains(.,'Like')]"))).click();
```

with no luck , just do not know why the button is not clicked , please help .. and thanks :)

Comment: Did you sign-in facebook yet?

Comment: sure i did .. every thing goes will even the click goes with no error ,, but it does not actually got clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try cssSelector below. It works on my machine.

```
By locator = By.cssSelector("a[data-testid='fb-ufi-likelink']");
driver.findElement(locator).click();
```

If it doesn't work. Please give me the exception message.